# How to use Dapper in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, dapper, ormlite-servicestack

Currently, I am using OrmLite for DB operations. I am also planning to use Dapper ORM, but can anyone point me how to integrate DapperORM in ServiceStack. Do I need to implement both IDbConnection and IDbConnectionFactory interfaces with Dapper and plugin into the container.

```
  public override void Configure(Container container) {
        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
          c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString,
                                            SqlServerDialect.Provider));

        container.Register<IDbConnection>(c => c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection()).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);

      }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dapper works like OrmLite in that they're both extension methods over the underlying ADO.NET `System.Data.*` [IDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.aspx) interface. This means you can use both of them together on the **IDbConnection** retrieved from OrmLite's IDbConnectionFactory.

OrmLite includes a recent version of Dapper in [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) under the `ServiceStack.OrmLite.Dapper` namespace.

---

In v3.9.40 of ServiceStack, this embedded version of Dapper had their APIs changed to include a 'Dapper' suffix to avoid clashing with OrmLite methods of the same name. You **don't** have to register a Request-Scoped IDbConnection as ServiceStack's default [Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Service.cs#L77) class already retrieves it from the IDbConnectionFactory for you.

Given that, here's how you can access Dapper ORM APIs inside a ServiceStack service:

```
public class MyService : Service
{
    public object Any(Request request)
    {
        base.Db.QueryDapper(...);
        base.Db.QueryMultipleDapper(...);
        base.Db.MultiMapDapper(...);
        base.Db.ExecuteDapper(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. And will it have any issues referencing razor library, my application is just API with rest services.

Comment: No, it's just a library which doesn't do anything if you don't enable the RazorFeature plugin.

Comment: as v3.9.44 is missing from  ServiceStack.Razor NuGet package, where is now ?

Comment: This answer appears to no longer be correct. The link to ServiceStack.Razor.Dapper results in a 404. I am unable, at present, to find a way to use "built-in" Dapper. Is Dapper no longer a part of ServiceStack?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about others, but due to the information regarding Dapper within the Razor namespace this answer confused me quite a bit.

In case others have a similar experience, I've attempted to answer this same question in a [basic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639251/servicestack-mars-multiple-active-result-sets-using-ormlite-and-output-paramet).