# ServiceStack.OrmLite get multiple result sets from a stored procedure

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I've been using SqlList() to receive result sets from SPs and it is handy.

```
var people = db.SqlList<Person>("EXEC GetRockstarsAged @age", new { "age", 42 });
```

but how can I use this OrmLite to get multiple result sets from a single SP?
Using the above approach only seems to retrieve the first result set.

Comment: I am not sure that OrmLite supports multiple result sets.

Comment: OrmLite supports calling SP's with [multiple output parameters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#stored-procedures-with-output-params) but not multiple result sets, although OrmLite does include an embedded version of Dapper in the `ServiceStack.OrmLite.Dapper` namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, ServiceStack.OrmLite does not support multiple result sets unless combined with Dapper. [ServiceStack MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets) using ORMLite and Output Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639251/servicestack-mars-multiple-active-result-sets-using-ormlite-and-output-paramet)

Alternatively, you can use the .Net SqlCommand.
[Return multiple recordsets from stored proc in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510901/return-multiple-recordsets-from-stored-proc-in-c-sharp)

ServiceStack.OrmLite V4 notes: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite

ServiceStack.OrmLite V3 notes: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/tree/v3