# servicestack.ormlite V3 how to execute procedure with output params?

Tags: .net, servicestack, procedure

I want use ServiceStak.Ormlite V3 to exec procedure with outpur params, But on the wiki on github for V3, there are no introduce about this. Anyone cany help? Thanks a lot

At Last I found a solution: [ServiceStack MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets) using ORMLite and Output Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639251/servicestack-mars-multiple-active-result-sets-using-ormlite-and-output-paramet)

Use Dapper & serviceStack V3 to exec proc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OrmLite API's required to support [Stored Procedure with output parameters](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/stored-procedures#stored-procedures-with-output-params) were first added in OrmLite **v4**. They are not available in the older [OrmLite v3](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/tree/v3) releases.

Comment: so it's mean, I can not use V3 to exec proc with  output params?